# How do you convert the image preview in finder for a grayscale image that was converted from a color image using Image Magick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, finder

I have a script to convert images into grayscale tiffs. All is working well except, when the file is complete, it is still showing a color image in mac's finder preview thumbnail. I am not sure if there is an option I am overlooking. I have played around with -preview type and it is updating the thumbnail preview but is creating a contact sheet. Not sure if I am going about it the right way with -preview or what actually controls this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    echo "$f"
    /usr/local/bin/convert -density 300 "$f"[0] -resize 1000x1000 -density 300 -type grayscale \
      -define tiff:endian=msb -compress LZW -format tif "${f%.*}_GS.tiff" && mv "${f%.*}_GS.tiff" /Done && rm "$f"

done
```

Comment: I suggest that you post your question on the ImageMagick GIT forum at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick

Comment: Add -strip to your command. The preview will be removed and regenerated from the modified image.